# In AWS Step Function State Machines, how do you enable JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, state-machine, aws-step-functions

When making a call to a State Machine with `float('nan')` in the payload, the result hints to enable `JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS` because of the `Non-standard token 'NaN'` .

```py
import boto3
import json
client = boto3.client('stepfunctions', endpoint_url=endpoint_url)
client.start_sync_execution(stateMachineArn='state_machine_arn',
                            name='new-execution',
                            input=json.dumps({'foo': float('nan')})
```

(truncating)

```
InvalidExecutionInput                     Traceback (most recent call last)
...
~/opt/miniconda3/envs/pandars38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    674             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    675             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 676             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    677         else:
    678             return parsed_response

InvalidExecutionInput: An error occurred (InvalidExecutionInput) when calling the StartSyncExecution operation: Invalid State Machine Execution Input: 'Non-standard token 'NaN': enable JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS to allow'
```

(wrapping)

```
InvalidExecutionInput: 
    An error occurred (InvalidExecutionInput) when calling the StartSyncExecution operation: 
    Invalid State Machine Execution Input: 
    'Non-standard token 'NaN': enable JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS to allow'
```

The same exception happens with the numpy `np.nan` as well.

Comment: hi, not sure if this might be of interest https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=761953 or perhaps change the type to be a string so non-standard values like NaN can be included?

Comment: Thanks, yea for now I'm just changing any NaN to essentially null , but just curious if someone knows how to access this cryptic `JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS` haha.

Answer (score 0):

NaN is not a valid JSON value according to the official JSON specifications.
https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Step Functions only supports standard tokens which conform to the official JSON specifications.

I suggest to encode your NaN to null.

Comment: Yep using that work around but I'm specifically wondering about how the error message is saying "enable JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS to allow" so I don't know if this is a super low level error that we have no control over but just curious.